# How can I connect to my phpmysql login page

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I have just downloaded phpmyadmin using a package on Linux.

```
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-zip php-gd php-json php-curl
 sudo phpenmod mbstring
 sudo systemctl restart apache2
 sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    . . .
 sudo systemctl restart apache2
 sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess
```

ERROR MESSAGE

> Not Found
> The requested URL was not found on this server.
> Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at beer.com Port 80"
> when typing localhost/PHPMyAdmin or http://nameofmyproject/phpmyadmin

Thanks for your help!

Comment: ```http://localhost/phpmyadmin/``` is where wou will find phpmyadmin login page

Comment: I get a Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80